# javascript datatable filter option not working

Tags: javascript, html

my filter columns are

```
<select id="filter">
<option value="Main Banner">Main Banner</option>
<option value="Right Banner">Right Banner</option>
</select>
```

my tables are

```
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 </table>
```

my datatable scipts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var table = $('#example1').dataTable( {
"aoColumnDefs": [
{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0, 3, 4 ] }
]});
$('#example2').dataTable({
"bPaginate": true,
"bLengthChange": false,
"bFilter": false,
"bSort": true,
"bInfo": true,
"bAutoWidth": false
});
});
</script>
```

my filter scripts are

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#filter").on('change', function() {
//filter by selected value on second column
table.column(1).search($(this).val()).draw();
});    
</script>
```

in dropdown list the main banner and right banner comes but on change not working...

here the filter options are not working...

Please help me...

Try to fix this....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#filter").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#filter").filter(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
  
  </script>
```